# Native boot on Hyper-V VHDX failed with inaccessible boot device error

Tags: hyper-v

I create a new virtual machine in Hyper-V (generation 2, guest GPT, host GPT), then I installed Windows 10 on it. It works well.
Then I wanted to natively boot on the newly created VHDX.
I used diskpart to assign the letter W: to the Windows partition.
I did `bcdboot W:\Windows /d` to add a new entry in the boot menu.
When I select my new entry in the boot menu, the computer restart and failed with the `inaccessible boot device` error on a BSOD.

Does anyone know what I missed or how to get more details to fix this issue?

Additional info:

- BitLocker encrypts the C: drive where the host is running and where the VHDX is stored

In Disk Management, Disk 0 is the physical disk and Disk 1 is the mounted VHDX.
[image: Disk Management]

Added bootloader entry:

```
identifier   {20ef5b6c-8f46-11ec-ba9a-3887d5b5cb14}
device       vhd=[C:]\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\Windows.vhdx,locate=custom:12000002
path         \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description  Windows VHDX
locale       en-us
inherit      {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
isolatedcontext Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice     vhd=[C:]\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\Windows.vhdx,locate=custom:22000002
systemroot   \Windows
resumeobject {20ef5b6b-8f46-11ec-ba9a-3887d5b5cb14}
nx           OptIn
bootmenupolicy Standard
```

Comment: This might be an obvious answer, and I don't have the time to research before I ask it, when you installed Windows 10 on the VM was it installed in Legacy or UEFI mode?  I know Generation 2 supports UEFI, but what I don't know, is if that default mode is UEFI.  It certainly is NOT the default when dealing with other hypervisors like VMware and VirtualBox.  It's also important to verify that the host OS is indeed installed in UEFI mode instead of Legacy mode. I know the BCD says it is but a confirmation would be nice.

Comment: You might find [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu?view=windows-11) helpful and perhaps tell us what you did NOT do from that article.

Comment: Thank @Ramhound for your feedback. The host and guest partition style is GPT. The difference with the Microsoft doc link is that I created the virtual machine with the Hyper-V manager and I ran it to install Windows.

Comment: Can you try Microsoft’s process?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the vhdx can not be stored on a Bitlocker encrypted drive, but inside the vhdx you can use Bitlocker again. e.g. I typically create a vhdx, set up the Windows machine inside the vhdx with Hypervisor, but without activating Bitlocker. Then do the boot entry magic and once I natively started from the vhdx activate Bitlocker. Otherwise, you need to run a Bitlocker recovery once you native boot as Hyper-V TPM is different from the one on the physical machine you natively boot from.